# Nullable Datetime From Derived Column

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, null, ssis-2012

Extracting data from a flat file. Field in question comes in as a string and is formatted to fit db column of type Datetime. Field allows null in the database and file contains nulls and valid strings that successfully convert to dates in this field.

SSIS is throwing an error when I try and pass the nulls on to the database.

### Error

> Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

### Data Conversion Code

```
([PO Scheduled Ship Date] == "") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],7,2))
```

### DataViewer Sample

[image: DataViewer Sample]

### DB Column Definition

[image: DB Column Definition]

Comment: ([PO Scheduled Ship Date] == "" || [PO Scheduled Ship Date] == "NULL") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],7,2)) Does changing the expression to this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Culprit was data outside of the date range ex. "00010101".

Comment: How did it run then when u removed the nulls?

Comment: Null records contained the invalid date strings as well. Pure coincidence and my awesome luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing your expression to -

```
 (TRIM([PO Scheduled Ship Date]) == "" || TRIM([PO Scheduled Ship Date]) == "NULL") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([PO Scheduled Ship Date],7,2))
```

Comment: can you double check and confirm column definition in database is datetime?